# HP-UFT 12.02: Disable ticket creation in ALM after each failed test

Tags: automation, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft, alm

I am running sets of Sanity test almost daily. For each failed test that i run from HP-ALM i get an email and a new created ticket in ALM.
How can i disable the creation of the tickets? I still need to see the results in ALM but i don't want every day to close all this tickets when the test success on the second run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From withing HP UFT 12.54, click on

Tools -> Options -> GUI Testing Tab -> Test Runs menu item screen

Make sure that the Submit a defect to ALM for each failed step is **unchecked**.

[image: Tools>Options>GUI Testing Tab> Test Runs menu Item Screen]

**resource**: https://community.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/QTP-Auto-defect-and-QC-Scheduled-run/td-p/2391952